Cost of Laos visa
I will be visiting Thailand soon and I hope to make a side trip by land to Laos.  I just checked the eVisa and I was surprised that it costs over $50.  This is considerably more than any other eVisa which I have applied for.  I don't think that I fell for a scam site but I guess that it is possible.  The address ended in gov.la Laos eVisa site
I believe that it is possible to get a visa on arrival.  Does anyone know the up to date cost?  Is it possible to get the visa in Bangkok?  (I did that previously for Vietnam.)
I am a dual UK / Irish citizen.

Visas are often on the condition of reciprocity. It may be that the UK charges Laos citizens $50 for visas as well.

@littleadv It could be.  If I must pay $50 then I will but I wanted to check other options first.

@littleadv UK charges a whopping 159usd for a 6 month (<shortest validity offered) visitor visa for laos citizens. And indeed, UK is the most I've ever paid for a visitor visa myself (230eur for 6month visa and mandatory fee for fingerprinting, plus 60ish to have my passport shipped back and the trains to give fingerprints in berlin). Laos is being much nicer to UK citizens than reciprocity here.

@ave Visa prices are getting very expensive here.  I am just jealous of my wife.  While I go to Laos, she will go to Australia; her ETA was free.  Of course, the relative costs will flip once we arrive.

At time of writing, visas on arrival for most nationalities including the UK cost US$40.  Yes, this is cheaper than the e-Visa; the price you pay is that you'll need to queue up in the VOA line and do payments etc on the spot, instead of breezing straight to passport control.
The pricing of visas from embassies varies by location but is almost always more expensive and more hassle than VOA, so there's really no reason to bother with this.

Thanks.  So, not a great saving.  Another reason that I backed out of the online application was that it wanted an address in Laos.  I don't have anything booked yet and I did not want to risk a vague "hotel in Vientiane" since the cost was high.  I might wait until I am in Thailand and get local friend to help me.

@badjohn Happy to help. In my experience all you need to get a Lao visa is money and a pulse, and I suspect the latter is optional.

My plan now is: get to Thailand, use friends to help choose a route and accommodation for the first night at least, and then apply for an eVisa.  One of the friends is half-Lao and can speak the language (in addition to English, Thai, and Japanese).

I am a UK national and have entered Laos 3 times as a visitor. Twice by air at Luang Prabang and once at the border crossing from Thailand near the Golden Triangle. In all 3 cases I got a visa on arrival. The process took about 10 minutes. I needed 2 photos and the visa fee in US dollars (cash).

As a further data point in October 2024.
By the time, I had my train and hotel booked, there was only a day left.  The eVisa said that it would take up to three days so I did not apply.
I took a train from Bangkok to Vientiane and arrived in Kamsavath station where the Lao immigration happened.  The Thai exit check was at the previous station in Thailand.
The visa on arrival was quite easy.  A fairly simple form and a short queue.  I had an ID photo and a variety of currencies in cash.  I was a little concerned that I would not be able to make the exact USD amount and I might have to give 100USD and get no change.  I was asked for 1700THB and I accepted that.  I did not inquire about other currencies.  I even got change in THB from 2000.
It would have been almost as quick as having a visa but I made a mistake.  The queues were not clear.  After I got my visa, I joined the single queue for passport checking.  When I got to the end, I was told that I could have left immediately.  If I had, I might have overtaken those with a visa.
There were 3 typical passport checking booths labelled: Diplomatic, Passports (presumably all), and ASEAN but they were not in use.  Both visa on arrival and others queued at small office windows.  Quite chaotic.
Many people did not have suitable or sufficient cash.  Some were escorted to the bureau de change and some were trusted alone.
Leaving was also quick and easy but you need to pay 10,000LAK (less than 0.50 GBP/USD/EUR).

This must have been a very recent trip since Kamsavath station is just open recently to train traffic from Thailand

Yes, it was a few days ago.  I was in Laos when I wrote that.  I have added the date and some exit detail.


I believe that it is possible to get a visa on arrival.

That depends on which checkpoint you use. Some offer visa on arrival, some don't. Official list from immigration.gov.la:


Acceptance of e-Visas is even more limited than VOA.
